# Stop selection from dragging started inside a canvas then dropped outside a canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drag-and-drop

When I drag from inside the canvas then drop outside of a canvas, normal form element become selected.  How do I prevent normal element from outside the canvas be selected?

I already added all these to my event functions:

```
            if(e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
            if(e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
            e.cancelBubble=true;
            e.returnValue=false;
```

I added this to all relevant events:  onmousedown, onmouseup, onmouseout, for the canvas.

Comment: This piece of code belongs to which event listener?

Comment: I added it to all:  onmousedown, onmouseup, onmouseout, for the canvas.

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` should prevent a drag that starts inside the canvas and continues outside & over another element from selecting that other element.

Comment: Could you make a jsFiddle of the issue? Or show a screenshot?